# FileNotFound Exception while attempting to read excel file (.xlsx) from internal storage in android

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel (.xlsx) file in the internal storage on my android phone. I am able to select the excel file but when I make a File object, I get the exception "FileNotFoundException" (Goal:- is to select an excel file and then read it).

In Activity Class "Import"  ---> I have a button, On Click of a button (i.e OnClick method) I had written below-mentioned code:-

```
 Intent chooseFile = new Intent();
                    chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    chooseFile.setType("*/*");
                    chooseFile.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file"), PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After this in onActivityResult -->

```
 @Override
 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE)
        {

            try {

            Uri uri = data.getData();            

              File file = new File(uri.getPath());


                FileInputStream myInputStream=new FileInputStream(file);

                OPCPackage myFileSystem=OPCPackage.open(myInputStream);
                XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook=new XSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
                XSSFSheet mySheet=myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

                Iterator<Row> rowIterator= mySheet.rowIterator();
                int rowNumber=0;

                while(rowIterator.hasNext())
                {
                   
                    XSSFRow myRow=(XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

                    if(rowNumber!=0)
                    {
                        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=myRow.cellIterator();
                        int columnNumber=0;
                        while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                        {
                            XSSFCell myCell=(XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();

                            if(columnNumber==0)
                            {
                               String Name=myCell.toString());
                            }
                            if(columnNumber==1)
                            {
                                String RollNumber=myCell.toString());
                            }
                            columnNumber++;
                        }
                    }
                        rowNumber++;
                }
            } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml-->

added Permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application>
 <activity android:name=".ui.home.Import"/>  //not a launcher activity

</application>
```

I tried a lot to find the answer online but till now I am not able to do it correctly. After a lot of attempts and reference, I am putting this question here, it will be very helpful if I can know what wrong I am doing.

Comment: I had used    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2"
                     implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2"   library

Comment: Please tell values of uri.toString() and uri.getPath();

Comment: uri.toString() -content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A7333               uri.getPath()- content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A7333

Comment: "msf%3A7333" should be the name of the file --but it is showing like this. Is any kind of encoding is happening here?

Comment: The value of uri.getPath() would be then: `/document/msf%3A7333`. The content provider knows which file belongs to it. Quite normal. You can query the content provider with this uri to obtain file name and size and such.

Comment: yes I am able to get the file name by querying the content provider but I am still not able to read the excel, it keeps throwing FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

> > ```
> >       File file = new File(uri.getPath());
> >
> >       FileInputStream myInputStream=new FileInputStream(file);
> > ```

Change to:

```
    InputStream myInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

You got a nice content scheme uri so use it.

Comment: after making the above change I am getting this exception                                                " java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar) "

Comment: is I am using the wrong library? I am not able to understand the error.

Comment: I do not understand the error too. You do not need any special library.